# Customize the tooltip on a MUI X Charts graph

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, mui-x, mui-x-charts

I am building a distance versus elevation line chart from GeoJSON data, and I would like to edit the tooltip's style and content.

Specifically, I am wondering how to:

- have the tooltip in relative position underneath the graph in a more discreet way, rather than ovrlapping like it is right now
- round the distance value to 2 decimals
- remove the ',' thousands separator from the distance value
- add ' m' to the distance value

[image: Graph]

```js
<LineChart
    margin={{ top: 5, bottom: 30, left: 55, right: 0 }}
    xAxis={[
        {
            min: Math.min(...xAxis),
            max: Math.max(...xAxis),
            data: xAxis,
            valueFormatter: (element) => `${element} km`,
        },
    ]}
    yAxis={[
        {
            tickNumber: 5,
            min: Math.min(...yAxis),
            max: Math.max(...yAxis),
            valueFormatter: (element) => `${element} m`,
        },
    ]}
    series={[
        {
            data: yAxis,
        },
    ]}
/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. have the tooltip in relative position underneath the graph in a more discreet way, rather than ovrlapping like it is right now

   That would be a great feature to do that with a single props. I created [an issue](https://github.com/mui/mui-x/issues/11484) to track progress on this idea
2. round the distance value to 2 decimals

   For that, the series config have a `valueFormatter`
3. remove the ',' thousands separator from the distance value
   add ' m' to the distance value

   That's solved with the `valueFormatter` too.

---

Here is a codesandbox with proposed solutions: https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/reverent-night-xfjytg?file=%2Fsrc%2FDemo.tsx%3A32%2C17